# Order post by date with ACF

Tags: custom-post-types, date, advanced-custom-fields

I implemented a custom post type for a class post. Now every post has a additional date picker called "date_event", my question is: Any have ideas how can i order the post for the last date of the label date_event?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This comes directly from [the ACF documentation](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/docs/field-types/date-picker/):

```
/*
*  Order Posts based on Date Picker value
*  this example expects the value to be saved in the format: yymmdd (JS) = Ymd (PHP)
*/

$posts = get_posts(array(
    'meta_key' => 'custom_order', // name of custom field
    'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
    'order' => 'ASC'
));

if( $posts )
{
    foreach( $posts as $post )
    {
        setup_postdata( $post );

        // ...

    }

    wp_reset_postdata(); // IMPORTANT - reset the $post object so the rest of the page works correctly
}
```

Comment: But @micheele, can i show only the events in this weeks?

Comment: That's possible though slightly more complicated (and a different question than what you asked above). First I'd get it showing all your posts ordered by your date field. Then post that code in a new question and ask how to limit the display by date range.